# C# more efficient way of comparing two collections

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have two collections

```
List<Car> currentCars = GetCurrentCars();
List<Car> newCars = GetNewCars();
```

I don't want to use foreach loop or something because i think there should be much better way of doing this.

I am looking for more efficient way to compare this collections and to get results:

1. List of cars which are in newCars and not in currentCars
2. List of cars which are not in newCars and in currentCars

Type Car has int property Id.

There was an answer, which is already deleted saying 
What i mean by saying efficient:  less code, less mechanics, and more readable cases

So thinking this way what is the cases i have?

What would be less code, less mechanics, and more readable cases?

Comment: The operations you are describing are "set differences". If you need to compute set differences a lot, or on large sets, then you should not be using List<T> in the first place. You should be using HashSet<T>, a data structure specifically optimized for computing these sorts of differences.

Comment: @Eric Lippert in my case it is very small sets(1-3 items), so i think there is no need in HashSet<T>.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `Except`:

```
var currentCarsNotInNewCars = currentCars.Except(newCars);
var newCarsNotInCurrentCars = newCars.Except(currentCars);
```

But this has no performance benefit over the `foreach` solution. It just looks cleaner.
Also, be aware of the fact, that you need to implement `IEquatable<T>` for your `Car` class, so the comparison is done on the ID and not on the reference.

Performancewise, a better approach would be to not use a `List<T>` but a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` with the ID as the key:

```
var currentCarsDictionary = currentCars.ToDictionary(x => x.ID);
var newCarsDictionary = newCars.ToDictionary(x => x.ID);

var currentCarsNotInNewCars = 
    currentCarsDictionary.Where(x => !newCarsDictionary.ContainsKey(x.Key))
                         .Select(x => x.Value);

var newCarsNotInCurrentCars = 
    newCarsDictionary.Where(x => !currentCarsDictionary.ContainsKey(x.Key))
                     .Select(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: But this is in essence a loop

Comment: @landoncz: I know. I think it's impossible to not use a loop.

Comment: I agree, technically you've got to use a loop unless you're going to do some crazy recursion (then you're going to have something un-maintainable and also risk blowing the stack).

Comment: It sure is, I was going to state that too but decided against it for brevity.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth first thing I've tried .Except() method but than i realized that i need to implement IEquatable<T> as you said, because i need comparison only by Id. The dictionary approach working well for me, so i don't need to implement any interfaces, i would do that but i am using auto generated classes(POCO, so Car it is autogenerated POCO class) so i dont want to modify t4 template or create partial class in order to implement IEquatable<T>.

Answer (score 16):

You can do it like this:

```
// 1) List of cars in newCars and not in currentCars
var newButNotCurrentCars = newCars.Except(currentCars);

// 2) List of cars in currentCars and not in newCars
var currentButNotNewCars = currentCars.Except(newCars);
```

The code uses the [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) extension method (available in .Net 3.5 and over).

I believe this fulfills your criteria of "less code, less mechanics, and more readable".

Comment: +1, LINQ is probably an easy way, especially with [Except()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx).

Comment: +1 but there is no guarantee that except will out perform a for each since it will most likely use Ienumerable and foreach any way.

Comment: He said he didn't want a foreach loop, this might be because of readability, he did not specify.  I'm going to side step the sticky issue of performance and give the most readable and maintainable code.

Answer (score 3):

If you start with them in `HashSet`s you can use the `Except` method.

```
HashSet<Car> currentCars = GetCurrentCars();
HashSet<Car> newCars = GetNewCars();

currentCars.Except(newCars);
newCars.Except(currentCars);
```

It would be much faster w/ a set than a list.  (Under the hood a list is just doing a foreach, sets can be optimized).

Comment: +1 for HashSet.  Although it will perform quicker it will consume more memory and the initial cost of populating the HashSet will be higher.  You should only use HashSet if you plan on using the same collection many times.

Comment: Very true.  The tradeoff is almost always size for speed, though.

Comment: Does HashSet have a special Except that is not the LINQ extension method? I think you meant ExceptWith, which mutates in-place.

Answer (score 2):

I'd override the `Equals` of a `Car` to compare by id and then you could use the `IEnumerable.Except` extension method. If you can't override the `Equals` you can create your own `IEqualityComparer<Car>` which compares two cars by id.

```
class CarComparer : IEqualityComparer<Car>
{
    public bool Equals(Car x, Car y)
    {
        return x != null && y != null && x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Car obj)
    {
        return obj == null ? 0 : obj.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the only way to do it without looping through each item in some fashion.

Comment: @landoncz: I don't see how this avoids a loop. He also suggests to use the `Except` extension method, although he misspelled it.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking he was overriding the entire list like this, D'oh, guess you can't add code to replies...

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ...

```
        List<Car> currentCars = new List<Car>();
        List<Car> newCars = new List<Car>();

        List<Car> currentButNotNew = currentCars.Where(c => !newCars.Contains(c)).ToList();
        List<Car> newButNotCurrent = newCars.Where(c => !currentCars.Contains(c)).ToList();
```

...but do not be fooled. It may be less code for you, but there will definitely be some for loops in there somewhere

EDIT: Didn't realise there was an Except method :(

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for efficency, implement IComparable on Cars (sorting on your unique ID) and use a SortedList. You can then walk through your collections together and evaluate your checks in O(n).  This of course comes with an added cost to List inserts to maintain the sorted nature.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the smaller list into an hash table based collection like HashSet or Dictionary and then iterate over the second list and check if the item exists in the hash table.

this will reduce the time from O(N^2) in the naive foreach inside foreach case to O(N).

This is the best you can do without knowing more about the lists (you may be able to do a *little* better if the lists are sorted for example, but, since you have to "touch" each car at least once to check if it's on the new car list you can never do better than O(N))

Answer (score 0):

If a comparison of the Id property will suffice you to say if a Car is equal to another, in order to avoid some sort of loop, you could override the List with your own class that keeps track of the items and uses the `IEqualityComparer` on the entire collection, like this:

```
class CarComparer : IList<Car>, IEquatable<CarComparer>
{
    public bool Equals(CarComparer other)
    {
        return object.Equals(GetHashCode(),other.GetHashCode());
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _runningHash;
    }

    public void Insert(int index, Car item)
    {
        // Update _runningHash here
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        // Update _runningHash here
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // More IList<Car> Overrides ....
}
```

Then, you just need to override the `Add`, `Remove`, etc and any other methods that might affect the items in the list.  You can then keep a private variable that is a hash of some sort of the Ids of the items in the list.  When overriding your `Equals` methods you can then just compare this private variable.  Not the cleanest approach by far (as you have to keep up with your hash variable), but it will result in you not having to loop through to do a comparison.  If it were me, I would just use Linq as some have mentioned here...