# What is the fastest way to compare these two collections?

Tags: c#

I am noticing a huge performance issue with trying to get a list of keys in a ConcurrentDictionary value object that exist in an IEnumerable collection as follows:

Customer object has:
string CustomerNumber;
string Location;

```
var CustomerDict = ConcurrentDictionary<string, Customer>();
var customers = IEnumerable<string>();
```

I am trying to get a list of the keys in the dictionary where the `customers.CustomerNumber` is in the dictionary.   What I have is below the removeItems takes a very long time to return:

```
var removeItems = CustomerDict
    .Where(w => customers.Any(c => c == w.Value.CustomerNumber))
    .Select(s => s.Key)
    .ToList();

foreach(var item in removeItems)
{
   CustomerDict.TryRemove(item, out _);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated what best to do with this.

Comment: list of the keys in the dictionary where the customers.CustomerNumber is in the dictionary ? You mean in the IEnumerable?

Comment: Also where is the innumerable coming from? It could be anything, a database, a network connection...

Comment: The fastest? Hash both collections and compare the hashes. Then do what all the other people wrote. With .Any you are doing a linear search. That's ok for small collections but get expensive fast.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# more efficient way of comparing two collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680487/c-sharp-more-efficient-way-of-comparing-two-collections)

Answer (score 3):

Make `customers` a `HashSet<string>`, who's [`Contains` method is `O(1)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=netcore-3.1#remarks):

```
var customers = HashSet<string>();

var removeItems = CustomerDict
    .Where(w => customers.Contains(w.Value.CustomerNumber))
    .Select(s => s.Key);
```

Currently, `Any` is iterating over `customers` every time which has an `O(n)` complexity.

Also you're call to `ToList` is superfluous: it adds an additional, unnecessary iteration over `customers`, not to mention increased memory usage.

Comment: +2 if I could!!

Comment: awesome thanks big mistake on that one the more I think about it.   Thanks again big help appreciate it.

Comment: even the try remove is slow as well but that helped a lot

Comment: Why not enumerate the ienumerable (customers) and check if the concurrentdictionary (customerdict) contains the key?

Comment: @RandRandom the key is not in the customers IEnumerable it is in the value object of the dictionary

Answer (score 2):

I think its better to create `HashSet` from `customers` in order to look faster,

```
HashSet<string> customersHashSet = new HashSet<string>(customers);

var removeItems = CustomerDict
                    .Where(c => customersHashSet.Contains(c.Value.CustomerNumber))
                    .Select(s => s.Key);

foreach (var item in removeItems)
{
    CustomerDict.TryRemove(item, out _);
}
```

When removing consider if you have many items in the HashSet ( relatively to the dictionary ) its maybe better to iterate over the dictionary and search in the HashSet, like this :

```
foreach (var item in CustomerDict.ToArray())
{
    if (customersHashSet.Contains(item.Value.CustomerNumber))
        CustomerDict.TryRemove(item.Key, out _);
}
```

Comment: Hey AnGG yes the remove is slow I need to look into that as well

Comment: perfect AnGG another big win there.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.Any` will do a linear scan of the underlying collection, which in your case is the key collection of your concurrent dictionary. This takes linear effort. It would be better to dump the keys into a local HashSet and then check the inclusion via `.Contains(w.Value.CustomerNumber)`. This becomes nearly constant effort.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just simply do this:

```
foreach(var customer in customers) //enumerate customers
   CustomerDict.TryRemove(customer, out _); //trytoremove the customer, won't do anything if the customer isn't found
```